# Строка в си,поменять слова местами

Tags: c, сортировка

Как поменять введенные слова местами, допустим я их как-то сортирую (по длине,алфавиту и т.п.) как можно поменять 1 слово с 3,5 со 2 и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку задача поставлена без каких-либо конкретных указаний на метод хранения слов и не указаны ограничения, привожу пример того, как можно обменять две строки местами, если их длина фиксирована заранее известной константой.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 20
char a[N] = "abacaba";
char b[N] = "bla-bla-bla";

static void swap (char * a, char * b) {
  char t;
  unsigned int i;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = t;
  }
}

int main() {  
  printf ("Before swap: %s %s\n", a, b);
  swap (a, b);
  printf ("After swap: %s %s\n", a, b);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: вот именно что нужно ввести строку,она заранее не известна(мне нужно по алфавиту отсортировать,сделал когда строка заранее известна,не знаю как сделать,чтоб строка вводилась,если надо могу скинуть)

Comment: Тут два варианта: либо делаете строки той длиной, которая заведомо больше самой длинной из возможных, либо работаете с указателями, как на то указал уже другой отвечающий (Harry). Если же вы надеетесь, что вам помогут написать программу, считывающую строки и правильно распределяющую их в памяти, то нужно было бы более точно формулировать задачу. Боюсь, при такой постановке она всё ещё непонятна.

Comment: а что именно непонятно?суть задачки в том,чтобы отсортировать строку,которая неизвестно заранее,по алфавиту

Comment: Поймите меня, пожалуйста, правильно: так задачи по программированию не ставятся. Нужно чётко указать: что и как вводится, каков метод хранения (или он вообще неизвестен и нужно  его продумать), а так, всё, что понятно читателю вашего вопроса так это то, что нужно поменять местами какие-то строки в процессе сортировки. Профессиональный программист может указать не менее поолудюжины способов решения вашей задачи, но ВСЕ они будут зависеть от конкретных условий, которых я лично здесь не вижу. Более того, здесь за Вас задачи не решают, а дают идеи. Я свою идею дал, дальше сами.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое по сути строка? Обычно под этим понимается указатель на ее первый символ, а не весь массив символов, составляющий строку. Вот и решение :)

Я думаю, что вам нужно использовать указатели и обменивать их. Пусть себе сами слова лежат, где лежали - а вы сортируйте их через указатели.

Думаю, идея понятна?

Ну, например:

```
char* words[] = { "ascgf", "eqwuyewb", "45e12qwx","zvcbvchsd","gfwdgh" };

int compare(const void* w1, const void* w2)
{
    return strcmp(*(char**)w1,*(char**)w2);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    qsort(words,sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]),sizeof(char*),compare);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: получается на каждое слово свой указатель?

Comment: Но вы же их и так вводите - значит, каждое слово в свой буфер, нет? И потом, производительность будет куда выше.

Comment: ну так если я ввожу 100 слов в строку,указатель то будет один правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @qwe Так у вас слова в пределах одной строки? тогда все существенно сложнее. Вам точно надо их хранить именно так - в строке? По мне, лучше их отсортировать отдельно и перезаписать в строку. Указатели прямо в строку можно использовать, но вместе с длинами слов - чтоб знать, что сравнивать. Обменивать слова в пределах строки - задача крайне сложная, особенно потому что будут портиться указатели на другие слова...

Comment: т.е вы предлагаете отдельно слова вводить(пословно),  отсортировать и результат в строку?

Comment: @qwe именно так он и предлагает сделать.

Answer (score 0):

смотри Бентли = Жемчужины программирования - главу про циклический сдвиг. в твоём случае пусть есть строка с где первое слово А в самом начале а второе В в самом конце т.е слово c==АБВ слово промежуток Б от нуля и более символов. тогда обмен места А с В это Ч(А),Ч(Б),Ч(В),Ч(с) где Ч это функция вращения на месте од левой по правую позиции не включительно (учись использовать полуоткрытые интервалы)в строке

Comment: Заметим, что при этом слово Б запросто уползает со своего места - поменяйте местами `AA` и `CCCCC` в `AA BBB CCCCC` - так что при сортировке нужно после каждого обмена выполнять полную переинициализацию слов...